# Download foto URL sem nome do arquivo

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

Eu uso para fazer download de arquivos e fotos o Glide ou o Retrofit mas nunca tinha me deparado com a necessidade que estou tendo agora.
A url é tipo http://meuserver.com/user/4564654/qrcode

o numero é o id do usuário e a qrcode é onde fica o arquivo de imagem do qrcode gerado pelo servidor, quando coloco essa URL no browser ele baixa a imagem normal como qualquer arquivo sendo feito download pelo navegador mas dentro do Android não sei como faço isso com o Glide ou o Retrofit.

Comment: Você quer baixar a imagem ou mostrá-la em um ImageView por exemplo?

Comment: Mostrar ela num ImageView!

Answer (score 0):

Glide e retrofit são bibliotecas, em resumo, para fins diferentes.
Com a retrofit você irá ao servidor e buscar o caminho da imagem ou até fazer o download do arquivo.

https://square.github.io/retrofit/

Utilizando esta biblioteca, você poderá trazer o caminho onde se encontra sua imagem, como dito em sua pergunta. Ao trazer a URL, utilize o glide para mostrá-la em seu imageView.

```
@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  ...
  ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);

  GlideApp.with(this).load("http://suaurl").into(imageView);
}
```

https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Comment: Sim, verdade o Glide serve para isso mas ele não baixa o arquivo da URL, ao que me parece ele so baixa se eu indicar o nome do arquivo 
Ex.: 'http://suaurl.com/user/564564/qrcode/user_564564_qrcode.png'
mas não se o endereço for: 
'http://suaurl.com/user/564564/qrcode'

Comment: O endereço deve ser completo, do arquivo, este endereço ele gera o que?  Uma lista de imagens? Você pode baixar o arquivo, salvar numa pasta local e abrir o caminho na imageView ou glide ou picasso

Comment: Ele gera um arqui, somente um arquivo dentro desse pasta, URL final.
Quando copio e colo a URL no chrome ele simplesmente baixa o arquivo, mas no Glide ele da erro, ele não baixa.

Comment: Então terá de fazer o load após o download do arquivo.